# How save as java project with src and lib folders in netbeans?

Tags: java

Iam new in java and when I exported the project in my computer and try to open that not appear the src and Lib folders in it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

you can manually place the all .java files on it on the src folder, first you've to select a wise option for your project like for simple java project select *java project* and for web application select *dynamic web application*.
then you can place your *.java* file on it.